# Socket programming with ktor-network unable to write string to server

Tags: android, sockets, kotlin, client, ktor-client

I am trying to build a client for a wifi device as server. I am using [ktor-network client docs](https://ktor.io/docs/servers-raw-sockets.html#usage) as a reference where it shows client implementation as follow which is so straight forward.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runBlocking {
        val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp().connect(InetSocketAddress("127.0.0.1", 2323))
        val input = socket.openReadChannel()
        val output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

        output.write("hello\r\n")
        val response = input.readUTF8Line()
        println("Server said: '$response'")
    }
}
```

But the problem is while I try to `output.write(USERNAME)` where `USERNAME` is String constant. And IDE shows **deprecated** warning for write function though I test with write method also the server is not giving any response. And I went through docs and it suggested to use writeFully instead of write. So I did the changes and tested it still no success. The desired output was server giving response "password:" but nothing was returned.

There is no problem in server side, because it is working in iOS implementation.

**Here is my implementation for my socket client:**

```
runBlocking {
    val socket = aSocket(ActorSelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp()
        .connect(InetSocketAddress(IP, PORT))

    input = socket.openReadChannel()
    output = socket.openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

    while (!socket.isClosed) {
        val response = input.readUTF8Line()
        Timber.e("Server said: '$response'")

        when(response){
            "login:"->{
                output.writeFully(USERNAME.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
            }
            "password:"->{
                output.writeFully(PASSWORD)
            }
        }

        delay(1000)
    }

    Timber.e("Stopped'")

}}catch (e: ConnectException){
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

I've tried `ByteWriteChannel` (class of output instance) class's these methods: `write(string)`,  `writeFully(byteArray)` & `writeStringUtf8(string)`. None worked!

Could you please help me out what's wrong here or what could be the solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

use `output.writeAvailable("$line\r\n".toByteArray())`

They just changed the API - this will write all the byes of your string to output.